# Merit gem - prevent users from voting more than once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merit-gem

I'm using Merit gem to add reputation system to my application for users that are logged in.

This is an example of how I'm using `score` to handle voting:

```
def initialize
  score 5, on: 'posts#upvote', to: :user
  score -5, on: 'posts#downvote', to: :user
  score 1, on: 'posts#upvote', to: :itself
  score -1, on: 'posts#downvote', to: :itself
end
```

The problem is that with this solution, users can vote on the posts as many times as they want.  I would like users to only have a single vote per post.  Is there any way to prevent users from voting multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a block to `score` to determine whether it should allow or not.  See [Merit: Defining Rules](https://github.com/merit-gem/merit#defining-rules-1) for more information.

This code updates what you had provided to give an example of how you might implement it in your app:

```
def initialize
  score 5, on: 'posts#upvote', to: :user {|topic| topic.voted?(@user) }
  score -5, on: 'posts#downvote', to: :user {|topic| topic.voted?(@user) }
  score 1, on: 'posts#upvote', to: :itself {|topic| topic.voted?(@user) }
  score -1, on: 'posts#downvote', to: :itself {|topic| topic.voted?(@user) }
end
```

This assumes that you have (or can build) a method to determine if a user has already voted on a topic.  In this case, the method is `voted?` on the topic that you're allowing votes on.

If you want to allow the user to only vote once, but to reverse a previously cast vote (like SO allows), you can handle that in the block, as well.  The complexity of the condition evaluated in the block is entirely up to you.